# How do I set an attribute on a prop after an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with an onClick event that sends a value to my state and should remove it from the state on a second click:

```
<button 
type="button" 
value={posts.index} 
onClick={this.props.data ? this.props.remove : this.props.add}
key={cont._id}
data={-1}
>
```

My problem is that I dunno how to set the data attribute to 1 after the first click, so the second click would fire the remove function. How do I achieve that?

action creator

```
    export function add(e) {
      return{
        type: ADD,
        payload: e.target.value
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the `data` attribute in prop contains the value you want the `data` attribute to contain.

First, ensure that in the parent component, `data` is defined as a `state` property, so that it can be manipulated to affect both the parent and the button.

Next, define the `add()` and `remove()` functions to look like:

```
add() {
  this.setState({data: this.state.data + 1});
}

remove() {
  this.setState({data: this.state.data - 1});
}
```

And of course, the constructor bind to `this` scope (still on the parent)

```
constructor(props, context) {
  this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  this.remove = this.remove.bind(this)
}
```

With these done, you can then define your button as:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  value={posts.index} 
  onClick={this.props.data ? this.props.remove : this.props.add}
  key={cont._id}
  data={this.props.data} >
```

React strongest belief is that changes in the DOM be triggered by data. With this setup, anytime you make any change to the parent data attribute by calling the `add()` or `remove()` callback, the button is re-rendered to reflect the new value of data.

Answer (score 2):

Set the value before the return.

```
render() {
   const buttonAction = this.props.data ? this.props.remove : this.props.add
   return ( 
     <button 
      type="button" 
      value={posts.index} 
      onClick={buttonAction}
      key={cont._id}
      data={this.props.data}> 
    )
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I must be missing something where do you set the data attribute to 1 there?

Comment: I presumed those were in the add and remove functions.

Comment: Well I'm having a problem with that as well, I'm adding my action creator to the post. The only way I can came up at this late hour is through the state, but I'm sure there's a simpler solution no?

Comment: How do you set the attribute from the action?

Comment: Have data set to this.props.data and then alter data via add or remove?

Comment: that's a problem when the action looks like this: [REMOVE]: (state, action) => ({...state, picking:state.picking.filter(item => item !== action.payload)}) oh and it goes to a combined reducer from there so I'm not sure where to handle the data attribute change. Can I fire an extra function with each onClick just to handle the data set?